# WSO2: Greg and ESB with shared registry issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-esb

I follow the guide *Governance Partition in a Remote Registry* found in WSO2 Documentaton. It seems to work fine but I am facing a strange problem. Let me explain my setup first.

**Governance registry instalation**

- Installed GREG 4.5.3
- Set the offset to 1 in order to GREG console mgmt runs on port 9444 (carbon.xml)
- Create mysql database "wso2greg_reg" (for local/config/governance registry)
- Updated datasource WSO2_CARBON_DB to point to wso2greg_reg database (master-datasources.xml)
- Enabled clustering (axis2.xml)
- Run GREG server with -Dsetup option in order to create all tables

**Enterprise Service Bus instalation**

- Installed ESB 4.6.0
- Set the offset to 2 in order to ESB console mgmt runs on port 9445 (carbon.xml)
- Create mysql database "wso2esb_reg" (for local/config registry)
- Updated datasource WSO2_CARBON_DB to point to wso2esb_reg database (master-datasources.xml)
- Added datasource WSO2_GREG_DB to point to wso2greg_reg database (master-datasources.xml)
- Enabled clustering (axis2.xml)
- Set registry.xml to mount governance registry using wso2greg_reg database
- Run ESB server with -Dsetup option in order to create all tables

My problem is happening when I start the two servers, dependening on which was the first server started I have diferent problems on the console managmenet of the secondly started server.

**First case:**

I start GREG first and ESB in second. When navigating to ESB Console MGMT, I am unable to add a new Pass Through Proxy, the respetive form is not showing and exceptions are logged to the ESB logs (see [logs](http://pastebin.com/KCA5X37w)).

**Second case:**

I start ESB first and GREG in second. When navigating to GREG Console MGMT, the metadata menu is empty and exceptions are loged to the GREG logs (see [logs](http://pastebin.com/3pR4DYDW))

Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a link to the documentation you have been following?

Comment: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Governance+Partition+in+a+Remote+Registry

Answer (score 2):

You need to create only one mysql database. It is this database that is used in the master-datasources.xml config for both G-Reg and ESB instances. What happens is, the mysql database is used as the central database.

Pls try this out and check if you still encounter the issues mentioned.

Cheers,
Gillian

Comment: Hi,

I tried with a single mysql database but no success. 

For GREG master-datasources.xml, I updated the WSO2_CARBON_DB Datasource to point to the mysql database and for ESB I let unchanged the WSO2_CARBON_DB datasource and add a new one (WSO_CARBON_GREG_DB) to point to the same mysql database. I then added configuration to the ESB registry.xml to mount the governance registry and enabled clustering for the WSO2 servers as indicated in the documentation. Unfortunatly the problem I described remains.

Comment: Another thing I tried was to disabled clustering for GREG and it seems to solve the problem but the documentation says that clustering must be enabled on all WSO2 servers in order to use cache invalidation in configured nodes. Did I miss any configuration related to clustering?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think I might found what I am doing wrong.. By default GREG and ESB uses wso2.carbon.domain as domain name, since the two servers are of diferent kinds (ESB and GREG), should I name for example GREG to wso2.greg.domain and ESB to wso2.esb.domain??
I tried the refered configuration and it solves the problem but I don't know if cache invalidation at the event of any updates on the registry resources still works (the documentation I followed does not refer anything related to wso2 domain names).